# コーディングテスト問題「Triangle」について

Tags: python, python3, アルゴリズム

コーディングテスト練習サイトCodilityの「Triangle」という問題について、
問題の理解とコードがなぜあるケースでincorrectになるのかわからず困っています。

[Triangle coding task -Learn to Code - Codility](https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/6-sorting/triangle/)

[上記の問題について日本語で解説された記事](http://codility-lessons-jp.blogspot.com/2014/07/lesson-4-triangle.html)

テストケースについて以下の注意が表示されましたが、
これは問題の理解が不十分なままコードを書いてしまったことに起因するまちがいでしょうか。

`[1, 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 5] the solution returned a wrong answer (got 3 expected 1)`

実行したコード

```
import itertools

def solution(A):
    count = 0
    if len(A) < 3:
        return 0

    possible = list(itertools.combinations(A,3))
    possible = list(set(possible))
    print(possible)

    for i in range(len(possible)):
        check = possible[i]
        if check[0] + check[1] > check[2] and check[1] + check[2] > check[0] and check[2] + check[0] >check[1]:
            count += 1
    return count
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> returns 1 if there exists a triangular triplet for this array and returns 0 otherwise.
>   https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/6-sorting/triangle/

これは、三角形を構成可能なら `1` 、さもなくば `0` を返せ、という意味になります。記載されているコードは三角形の数を返しているようですが、実際には非ゼロならば1を返せば良いようです。

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。以後注意します。